# how to execute a function on items in many nested lists in python

Tags: python, list, recursion, nested-loops, nested-lists

I want to iterate through a ton of nested lists in python, and recursively tree into other lists. The list(s) will have the general format `[[1, [2, [3, [4, 5]]]], [7, [8, [9, [10, 11]]]]]`. For example, I would want to make another nested list without flattening the big list.

Expected output: `[[1, [2, [3, [4, [5, x]]]]], [7, [8, [9, [10, [11, y]]]]]]`

I have tried function recursion, and have made the function getChildren():

```
def getChildren(list):
    for item in list:
        item = [item, item + 1]
    return list
```

I believe that I am close. I want to do this all many times until a value at "the bottom".
So far, here's my code:

```
while True:
    layer = []
    for item in list: 
        item = getChildren(item)
        layer.append(item)
    list.append(layer)
```

But it's not working as expected. Any help?

Comment: Do you understand what recursion is? You are not calling the function from within itself ...

Comment: Yes, but I have no clue how to implement it. I've tried many code segments with recursion but couldn't figure it out, I will try to add them to the post

Comment: I strongly recommend never to name a variable `list` in python. `list` is the name of builtin class `list` that is used to build all lists. If you shadow that name by using it for a particular variable, weird stuff can happen. Here is a list of names of builtins to avoid in python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
L = [[1, [2, [3, [4, 5]]]], [7, [8, [9, [10, 11]]]]]

def getChildren(L):
    for indx, value in enumerate(L):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            getChildren(value)
        else:
            L[indx] = [value, value + 1]

getChildren(L)
print(L)
```

gives:

```
[[[1, 2], [[2, 3], [[3, 4], [[4, 5], [5, 6]]]]], [[7, 8], [[8, 9], [[9, 10], [[10, 11], [11, 12]]]]]]
```

OR

```
L = [[1, [2, [3, [4, 5]]]], [7, [8, [9, [10, 11]]]]]
def getChildren(L):
    if isinstance(L[1], list): 
        getChildren(L[1])
    else:
        L[1] = [ L[1], L[1]+1 ]
getChildren(L[0])
getChildren(L[1])
print(L)
```

which gives:

```
[[1, [2, [3, [4, [5, 6]]]]], [7, [8, [9, [10, [11, 12]]]]]]
[[1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6, 7]]]]]], [7, [8, [9, [10, [11, [12, 13]]]]]]]
[[1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6, [7, 8]]]]]]], [7, [8, [9, [10, [11, [12, [13, 14]]]]]]]]
```